# AJAX request to database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

There are many checkbox pages in my Rails application.

[image: Checkboxes]

When clicking on one checkbox, its id should immediately be written to database (I use postgresql)

Сheckbox id should be written to the table as an array.

[image: table]

**How to implement this with ajax?**

*An example of my checkbox:*

```
<input name="skill_list[127]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input class="m-enabled" id="skill_list_127" name="skill_list[127]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="skill_list_127">Zoomerang</label>
```

Comment: you canno''t interact directly with postgresql , you need to define your API with a back-end technology like Nodejs or PHP , and make http call with ajax  , https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs , https://www.airpair.com/js/jquery-ajax-post-tutorial you can follow theses links

Comment: You can make your form `remote: true` and submit the form when an input is clicked. In jquery that would write like `$( '#form input' ).on('click', function(e){ $( "#form" ).submit(); });` then all the form data will be sent to your controller as Ajax.

Comment: create a on click function when you click the  checkbox, also add a data attribute with id of the skill to the check box, When you click the check box make an ajax call, in the controller take the corresponding table row skill_id, push the data-attribute that you passed from the javascript to the array.update the skill_id with the new array

Answer (score 0):

*UserSkillList* controller:

```
def create
  skill_id = params[:skill_id].gsub(/\D/, '').to_i if params[:skill_id].present?

  @skill_record = UserSkillList.where(user_id: current_user.id).first

  @skill_record.skill_id += [skill_id]
  @skill_record.save
end
```

*app.js*:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkbox_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user_skill_list",
            data: {skill_id: checkbox_id}
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: In checkbox code, for attr id, result will be "skill_list_127".
There is string appended with id integer in the code. So seperate it first then use the id. Give something like : $(this).attr('id').split("_")[2]